# Laravel: InvalidArgumentException : Database [mysql] not configured

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've been trying for days now to get Laravel working. The current problem that I can't figure out is the database that is not being configured.

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laracms
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

database.php:

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'      => 'mysql',
        'host'        => env( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' ),
        'port'        => env( 'DB_PORT', '3306' ),
        'database'    => env( 'DB_DATABASE', 'laracms' ),
        'username'    => env( 'DB_USERNAME', 'homestead' ),
        'password'    => env( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'secret' ),
        'unix_socket' => env( 'DB_SOCKET', '' ),
        'charset'     => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation'   => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'      => '',
        'strict'      => true,
        'engine'      => null,
    ],
],
```

EDIT:

Laravel.log

```
[2018-12-05 15:59:34] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured          logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object]    (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at    /home/vagrant/code/laracms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Log Manager.php:167)
[stacktrace]
#0   /home/vagrant/code/laracms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(101): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->resolve(NULL)
#1 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(89): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->get(NULL)
#2 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(490): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->driver()
#3 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(114): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->error('syntax error, u...', Array)
#4 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#5 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(353): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#6 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#7 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#8 {main}
"} 
[2018-12-05 15:59:34] laravel.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected    ''connections'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']' {"exception":"   [object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code:   0): syntax error, unexpected ''connections'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING),   expecting ']' at /home/vagrant/code/laracms/config/database.php:45)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository))
#1 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(204): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#2 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(297): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#3 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(120): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#4 /home/vagrant/code/laracms/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Do you have a mysql server running on `127.0.0.1:3306`, with a database `laracms` and a user `homestead` with all rights on that database?

Comment: What is your problem..?

Comment: can u run `php artisan config:cache` command ?

Comment: It looks as if Laravel does not find your config file, I can reproduce this error if I remove the key from the database.php config file.

Comment: @PhilippPalmtag Which key? I don't see any key in my database.php file

Comment: The `mysql` array key in your `database.php` file

Comment: @koyera Have you tried to retrieve the config key anywhere in your application? Put `dd(config('database.connections'));` into `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`in the `boot()` method and show us what you get.

Comment: @PhilippPalmtag I put it there like you asked, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Thats strange. You should see a array listing of the available connection keys. Can youi post details from the `laravel.log` please?

Comment: @PhilippPalmtag check the post. It's there.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Database [mysql] not configured. If I ran php artisan cache:clear or config:cache I would get the same error. I solved it by going into laravel/bootstrap/cache and deleting the config.php file that was there, and then running the above commands again. I believe it was a file permission error that was preventing the cached config.php file from actually being cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got to reproduce your exact error by using the information from your log:

```
[2018-12-18 10:32:25] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:167)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(101): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->resolve(NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(89): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->get(NULL)
#2 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(490): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->driver()
#3 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(114): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->error('syntax error, u...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#5 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(314): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#6 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#7 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 {main}
"} 
[2018-12-18 10:32:25] laravel.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected ''connections'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']' {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected ''connections'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']' at /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/config/database.php:34)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository))
#1 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(204): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#2 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(162): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(146): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#4 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#5 /var/www/html/galaxus-explorer/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#6 {main}
"}
```

It looks to me like a syntax error, thus I cannot say why it is happening. Look what I did to produce the error, the quotations on the `connections` key:

```
'''connections''' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Please double check your `config/database.php` file. Maybe there are differences between your uploaded file and the local one. Something must be wrong with the `connections` key or something with the quotation somewhere before that. Best you post the whole file.